# A question on time taken in different frames of references

Tags: momentum, velocity, linear-algebra, relative-motion

Let us say , a swimmer has to swim upstream and downstream a river , between two points which are at distance "L" from each other . The swimmer can swim in still-water at velocity "Vs" , and the velocity of the river is "Vr".

Now in the frame or reference of the river bank (or,ground) , his velocity upstream is Vs-Vr, and downstream is Vs+Vr, so the total time taken is

T1=L{1/(Vs+Vr) + 1/(Vs-Vr)}.

Now if we observe the motion in the frame of reference of the river , the swimmer's velocity is Vs only , and as the distance is same , the time taken in this case is

T2=2L/Vs

But shouldn't the time come the same ,regardless of the frame of reference ? I've tried putting in some values of Vs and Vr also and they are certainly not equal .

Please help me out , and point out where am I making a mistake and what should be the correct way of solving in different frames if references .
Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to look at it is:

In the bank’s referential, the swimmer appears to swim at a speed:

Vs + Vr

between points A and B (separated by a distance L)

In the swimmer’s referential, the banks appears to move at a speed:

V = - Vs - Vr

Or

V = - (Vs + Vr )

So, basically the length between A and B is the same in both cases and so is the module of the speed (respectively of the swimmer or of the river bank, depending upon the point of vue (referential)).

Therefore, in both cases, the time needed to swim from A to B by is the same, as common intuition suggests.

T = L / ( Vs + Vr )